# What was Cassie planning to morph into when assaulting the Yeerk Pool?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

In the first Animorphs book [*The Invasion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invasion_(Animorphs)), the group decide to attack the Yeerk Pool in order to save Jake's brother Tom. In order to achieve this, they all acquire animal DNA that would be suitable for an attack (gorilla, elephant etc.).

However, Cassie gets taken by one of the Controllers before their attack, so they go to rescue her. They are supposedly ready to do the assault before she is kidnapped, yet in later books it is never addressed which form she had taken in order to attack the Yeerk Pool.

Had she acquired a form that was used in a later book in the series, or was she planning on acquiring another form later? As far as I remember her only DNA acquisition at this point was a horse from her farm. Was she planning on morphing into a horse for the attack?

Comment: She shook hands with the Ellimist, and planned to assault the Yeerk pool as a demigod, but got distracted and forgot.

Comment: @Liesmith Your username is very appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I remember her only DNA acquisition at this point was a horse from her farm. Was she planning on morphing into a horse for the attack?

On *page 78* we are given a clue:

> It turned out the other three had not been chased at all. They'd lost the guards easily, and had just gone on acquiring morphs while Marco and I were risking our lives in the tiger habitat.

Since "the other three" includes Cassie, it looks like Cassie did indeed acquire something at the zoo. This makes sense. The horse would have been a terrible idea. It is fair enough for flight, but sub-par, if not lousy, for a battle with bladed space monsters with Dracon beams. Marco's gorilla was probably needed due to its dexterous hands and feet.

**Edit:** More than two months later, I have now read every single Animorphs (including companion) books, and there were never any clues as to what Cassie acquired at the zoo. Every single morph she used later was accounted for in some other way.