# After the helicopter was destroyed, what happened to the bug fighter and the sharks?

Tags: animorphs

In [Animorphs #39, The Hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_(novel)) the Yeerks are chasing the Animorphs using a helicopter and a bug fighter. The Animorphs are in the ocean in dolphin morphs. The bug fighter is shooting at them, and they get greatly injured, bleeding into the water. Cassie flies very high up into the air, and tries to destroy the helicopter by falling onto it in whale morph. As she is descending, she can see sharks heading for the others. The helicopter does get destroyed, and Cassie falls into the ocean. But she is greatly injured, and she goes unconscious.

The others manage to get Cassie to demorph. And she becomes conscious again. Cassie stays in human form for a while, having a conversation with the others before she finally morphs to dolphin too, and they all go home.

But what happened to the bug fighter? While Cassie was falling it was firing at the Animorphs, nearly killing them. Did it somehow lose sight of them when the helicopter was destroyed? I know it needed the device in the helicopter to track them, but couldn't it see them from the air? It had nearly killed them prior to that.

Also, what happened to the sharks? Did the Animorphs demorph and morph to heal the injuries of their dolphin bodies, causing the sharks to lose interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Bug  fighter retreated or was destroyed

The Yeerks were able to track the Animorphs with a Helmacron device that responds to morphing energy:

> "I'll notify the others, but we have to move on this. The Yeerks have
> managed to repair the Helmacron ship and they've reactivated the
> sensors that locate morphing energy."
>
> —*Animorphs: The Hidden*

The description of the Bug fighter's actions in the book certainly makes it seem as if it needs the helicopter for real-time combat:

> The dolphins resurfaced farther out. The helicopter moved again,
> hovering over them while the Bug fighter blasted away with the Dracon
> beams.
>
> —*Animorphs: The Hidden*

The helicopter doesn't seem to be launching any attacks, suggesting that its only purpose is to mark the dolphins' location.

> While the Bug fighter swooped and buzzed low over the ocean, the
> helicopter was hovering like a giant dragonfly in one spot — directly
> above where the dolphins were last seen.
>
> —*Animorphs: The Hidden*

Interestingly, the previous quotes also seem to indicate that whatever energy is emitted by people in morph cannot penetrate water, else the helicopter would be able to track them underwater, not wait for them to resurface and *then* move.

Dolphins can stay submerged for *15 to 17 minutes*, and would only need to resurface briefly for air. Without the Helmacron sensors to know exactly where the Animorphs were surfacing, the Bug fighter could easily miss them. *If* the Animoprhs were all in dolphin morph, it would entirely make sense that they could evade the Bug fighter. **As it was, though, they had to support Cassie (in human form), meaning that they must have been above water.**

Even with the pilots relying purely on their vision, they surely would have been able to spot five dolphins and one human above-water. **One possibility, then, is that the Bug fighter fled.** Maybe they didn't like their chances after the helicopter had been destroyed. Or maybe they figured that they would be unable to track the Animorphs without the helicopter (not knowing that they would have to support another of their number above-water), and so abandoned the search. Or maybe Visser Three called them back to yell at them.

**Another likely possibility is that the Bug fighter was destroyed**

It was directly below the helicopter when the helicopter exploded.

> The Bug fighter swooped in below the helicopter, blasting the wounded,
> surfacing dolphins again and again.
>
> —*Animorphs: The Hidden*

It is not inconceivable that it could have been caught up the explosion.

### The sharks lost interest or were repelled

> <Hey, you'd yell, too, if sharks were eyeing you up like sushi,> Marco
> retorted.
>
> <We were all in the water, remember?> Rachel purred.
>
> <But you weren't pumping out blood like a fire hydrant,> Marco said.
>
> —*Animorphs: The Hidden*

It seems likely from the use of the word "weren't"  that they are no longer bleeding. Since the only plausible way for this to be the case would be by morphing, that must be what happened.

While there are many ways that the Animorphs could have caused the sharks to retreat (e.g. by morphing into something large and frightening), none of these are mentioned. So either the sharks lost interest in them, or (when not distracted by being shot at) they were able to drive them off.

Comment: @Fiksdal - Well, I think they might have thought the Animorphs had some sort of bomb, after the helicopter blew. And as mentioned, it is quite possible that the fighter simply was caught up in the explosion.

Comment: @Fiksdal - Y'know, you've asked every single [tag:yeerks] question.

Comment: Haha, yes, I know, I actually looked at the tag earlier today and noticed the same thing :D I'm also the one who created the tag :) [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132398/64504) about an attack on the Yeerk pool also involves Yeerks to some degree, so I guess it could also potentially be tagged with that tag :) I'll probably be asking some more Animorphs questions here in the future, I know there are several fans around. So maybe we can increase the activity.